# Display Serial Number (rownum) along with the data in mysql by eliminating the duplicates in my table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, rownum

I have a Table which contains duplicate data in one column. I want to display unique data along with the rownum or serial number. my table has fields table1(tno,tname), in where tname has duplicate values, and I want to display the unique 'tname' data.

Comment: for row number, you can use a custom function foudn below
http://datamakessense.com/mysql-rownum-row-number-function/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @auto:=0;
SELECT @auto:=@auto+1 rownum, tname 
FROM table1 GROUP BY tname
```

Comment: If you find my answer gives you way to get coeect answer than accept the answer and upvote it

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
Select tname, tno
from table1
group by tname having count(*)=1
```

Comment: I asked you to display rownumber not tno

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your contributions all... I got the answer. If you get the better answer than this just share..

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 sno, a.tname FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tname from Table1) a, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r  limit 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UUID()

select UUID() as uniqueID FROM table1